GA Server side tagging custom event not firing even when the event name is correctly matched
Our team is new to GA server-side tagging. We have the purchase event setup on the web container and managed to receive the event on the server-side container; as shown on the screenshots below. The event name received on server side is exactly 'purchase' but the event is not fired.
Is it because the event is duplicated? We have tried to remove the trigger on web container but once removed, the server container will no longer receive the event. Anyone can help? Much appreciated.
Server side event trigger
Server side container event
Have the event triggered and fired on server side container
